# how to dynamically create multiple select statement and store it in a datatable

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datatable

the case here is the number of columns i would like to store to the datatable depends on the number of available data. i would need a multiple select statements to collect all the data.

```
select test_result.stud_id,test_info.max_score,
test_result.test_score 
from test_result left join test_info 
  on test_result.test_info_id = test_info.test_info_id 
where test_info.test_type_id = 1 and test_info.test_num = 1;
```

i would have to repeat this code over and over again until the test_num reaches the current maximum count. i was thinking of looping this code while storing it to the datatable.this is what i would like the datagridview would display.

```
|Quiz Number  | Quiz#1 | Quiz #2 | Quiz #3 |  Quiz #4 |  Quiz #5 |
|Max score    |    20  |    25   |    30   |    15    |    15    |
|student 1    |    18  |    22   |    25   |    12    |    14    |
|student 2    |    19  |    20   |    25   |    11    |    13    |
|student 3    |    20  |    24   |    20   |    12    |    11    |
```

the display of data would be in rows. so each row would require a different select statement in order to display the required data.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Looks like you may need PIVOT

Comment: im using mysql for my database and im using c# as my front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below will woek for you

```
select 
test_result.stud_id,
max(case when test_result.test_info_id =1 then test_result.test_score end) as quiz_1,
max(case when test_result.test_info_id =2 then test_result.test_score end) as quiz_2,
max(case when test_result.test_info_id =3 then test_result.test_score end) as quiz_3,
.
.
. 
from test_result left join test_info 
  on test_result.test_info_id = test_info.test_info_id 
where test_info.test_type_id = 1 and test_info.test_num = 1
group by test_result.stud_id;
```

Comment: thanks man it worked. but i was wondering if how can i make the cases dynamic or is it even possible? coz the test_info_id are all dependent on my selected combo box items